# Interrupt for variable initialization

Tags: c, interrupt-handling

Im following James Molloy`s guide to create small OS and now i stuck on interrupt. I dont really understand how to call my interrupt handlers instead of this command:

```c
    asm volatile("int $0x21");
```

*Main file*

```c
    #include "monitor.h"
    #include "multiboot.h"
    #include "descriptor_tables.h"
    #include "timer.h"
    #include "paging.h"
    #include "simple.h"

    int main(struct multiboot *mboot_ptr){
     // Initialise all the ISRs and segmentation
        init_descriptor_tables();
     // Initialise the screen (by clearing it)
        monitor_clear();
        monitor_write("Hello, paging world!\n");          
        init_simple();
        asm volatile("int $0x21");
        return 0;
    }
```

Where 0x21 is an interrupt`s number in vector.Is there a method to make a interrupt using a *c* command?

For example i want use this commands:

```c
    char c; // for interrupt created and handler allocate memory for char/int etc.
    char c = 'a'; // allocate + assing 
    c; // get value
    c = 'b'; // assing new value
```

Is there any possible way to do it?

Comment: There is no notion of interrupts in standard C.

Comment: Oh , ok
Is there a way to do it in asm?

Comment: "allocate + assing" ?  Is that the end of allocation?  Perhaps "allocate + assign"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interrupts are generated by the CPU itself.

While C is commonly used to write the interrupt *handlers* in the kernel, there is no unique facility (or machine model) dictating their creation using it.

Comment: But how system allocate memory in simple main program with several variables?

Comment: It's specific to the operating system. In Linux, your program calls `malloc()` which in turns invokes the system call `brk()`. On the other side, the kernel (and memory management unit, if appropriate) is then responsible for handling the translation of that page to an underlying piece of physical memory.